# AWS-S3 Bucket reading permissions issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am facing an issue regarding the permissions on my bucket newly created on AWS.

I have created a bucket on AWS-S3 so I can store pictures from my application uploaded by users. Times to time I would go in, and delete the images.

The problem I am facing is that Amazon recommends a *Block all public access* permissions on your bucket hence I have a *Access Denied* error when I try to read my images in my application.

I have spent almost 2hours in their documentations, which I admit is a bit confusing to me and I would love if someone can help me resolve the issue.

I want to keep the bucket private, and signing at every request from my application with the secret key and secret Id to prevent unauthorized access. Below is the code I have and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
const awsSdk = require("aws-sdk");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3-transform");

awsSdk.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  accessKeyId: config.AWS_SECRET_ID,
  region: config.AWS_REGION
});

const awsStorage = multer({
   storage: multerS3({
   s3: s3,
   bucket: "bucketname",
   acl: "public-read",
   contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
   cacheControl: "max-age=31536000",
   metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, { fieldname: file.originalname });
   },
   key: (req, file, cb) => {
     cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname);
   }
 }),
 fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
   if (
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/png"
   ) {
    //adding the file to the body custom field
    req.body.files = req.files[0].fieldname;
    cb(null, true); // accept file
   } else {
    cb(null, false); //reject file
  }
}
```

Bucket policy - public (how to make it so I can singing with my secret key and id)

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You should use a **pre-signed URL**. See: [Upload files to Amazon S3 from the browser using pre-signed urls](https://medium.com/@aakashbanerjee/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-the-browser-using-pre-signed-urls-4602a9a90eb5)

Comment: You haven't included any code that actually uses `awsStorage` or shown us how your client application interacts with this code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I can see suspicious is the `public-read` acl. You most likely don't want to do that. You can read up on that topic here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

Other than that, tutorial that John Rotenstein should get you the rest of the way.